# How can i get rid of the scrollbar's white corners

Tags: html, scrollbar

So, i started building a site and successfully made a navbar, etc.
I started changing the scrollbar style, but when i do, there are some white corners which ruin the whole aspect of the site, here's a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhhyT.png
another picture with the full page:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbnz.png)

Thanks in advance :-)

Here's my css code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    bacgkround-color: #c7c7c7;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(330deg, #243a51 0%, #243a51 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #243a51 0%, #243a51 100%);
}
```

Comment: remove border-radius from ::-webkit-scrollbar-track

Comment: thanks for your reply. tried but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have border radius problem.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 10px;        // remove it
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(330deg, #243a51 0%, #243a51 100%);
   background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #243a51 0%, #243a51 100%);
}
```

Comment: so, basically there is no way of making the scrollbar rounded without that white space, right?